# Verificação de vídeos por usuário

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Estou desenvolvendo um site para mostrar vídeos inseridos pelos usuários.

Para isso fiz com js:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    var videoContainer_monitor = $("#video_monitor");
    var codigoVideo_monitor = $videos;
    $('#video_monitor').hide();

  $("#video_pendente").click(function(){
    $('#video_monitor').show();
    videoContainer_monitor.html(`
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" width="700" height="450" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/${codigoVideo_monitor}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`);
      })
  });
```

Ao clicar no botão do html da página:

```
<button type="button" id="video_pendente" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Videos pendentes</button>
```

Porém ali em **'$videos'** quero que selecione com base nos vídeos inseridos pelo usuário que está logado no site.

Segue abaixo a imagem do BD.

[image: BD]

Os vídeos que poderiam aparecer, teriam que ser respectivos ao campo **"monitor"** que serve para identificar o monitor. E em seguida, selecionar todos os campos **"link_video"**. Como faço para verificar o usuário logado e mostrar seus respectivos vídeos cadastrados? (Pode ser com php também, não necessariamente com js).

Não entendi as avaliações negativas, do que adianta negativar se não comentar.. como que a gente vai mudar as perguntas.. por isso tem tanta gente saindo do flow para outra plataforma.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Olá, Matheus!

Bom, não sei se entendi bem o problema, mas preparei um script para demonstrar como você pode buscar os vídeos pendentes de um usuário logado. Você pode vê-lo coms os códigos abaixo:

#### Base de dados:

```sql
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.7.29, for Linux (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: videos_stackoverflow
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Table structure for table `videos`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `videos`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `videos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nomecomp` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `urlvideo` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `descricao` text,
  `pendente` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `videos`
--

LOCK TABLES `videos` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `videos` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `videos` VALUES (1,'matheus','https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8iNczzhZmbc','video 1',0),(2,'matheus','https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8iNczzhZmbc','video 2',0),(3,'matheus','https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8iNczzhZmbc','video 3 - PENDENTE',1),(4,'matheus','https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8iNczzhZmbc','video 4 - PENDENTE',1),(5,'macario','https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8iNczzhZmbc','video 5',0),(6,'macario','https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8iNczzhZmbc','video 6 - PENDENTE',1),(7,'macario','https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8iNczzhZmbc','video 7 - PENDENTE',1),(8,'macario','https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8iNczzhZmbc','video 8 - PENDENTE',1),(9,'macario','https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8iNczzhZmbc','video 9 - PENDENTE',1);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `videos` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2020-04-13  9:22:05
```

#### Index.php

```php
<?php

    $servidor = 'localhost';
    $usuario  = 'root';
    $senha    = '';
    $banco    = 'videos_stackoverflow';
    $conexao  = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $banco);

    $consulta = "SELECT
                    *
                FROM
                    videos
                WHERE
                    videos.nomecomp     = 'macario'
                    AND videos.pendente = 1";

    $resultados       = mysqli_query($conexao, $consulta);
    $videos_pendentes = array();

    while ($video = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultados))
        $videos_pendentes[] = $video;

    mysqli_free_result($resultados);
    mysqli_close($conexao);

    $videos_pendentes = json_encode($videos_pendentes);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Vídeos Pendentes</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <h1 style="margin-top: 60px;">Listar vídeos pendentes</h1>
                <p>Por favor, clique no botão abaixo para listar os vídeos pendentes de um monitor.</p>
                <button id="btn-lista-videos-tabela"   class="btn btn-primary">Mostrar em tabela</button>
                <button id="btn-lista-videos-carousel" class="btn btn-primary">Mostrar em Carousel</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row" style="margin-top: 60px;">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <table id="tabela-videos" class="table" style="display: none;">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>#</th>
                            <th>Monitor</th>
                            <th>URL</th>
                            <th>Descrição</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="tabela-videos-corpo">
                        <!-- Nada aqui, por enquanto -->
                    </tbody>
                </table>


                <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" style="display: none;" data-ride="carousel">
                    <ol id="carousel-indicadores" class="carousel-indicators"></ol>
                    <div id="carousel-itens" class="carousel-inner"></div>

                    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Anterior</span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Próximo</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {            
            const videos_pendentes = JSON.parse(<?php echo json_encode($videos_pendentes) ?>);

            $('#btn-lista-videos-tabela').click(function() {
                let html = '';

                if (videos_pendentes.length > 0) {
                    videos_pendentes.forEach(function(video) {
                        html += '<tr>';
                        html += '   <td>' + video.id        + '</td>';
                        html += '   <td>' + video.nomecomp  + '</td>';
                        html += '   <td>' + video.urlvideo  + '</td>';
                        html += '   <td>' + video.descricao + '</td>';
                        html += '</tr>';
                    });


                    $('#tabela-videos-corpo').html( html );
                    $('#tabela-videos').show();

                } else {

                    alert('Nenhum vídeo pendente');

                }
            });



            $('#btn-lista-videos-carousel').click(function() {
                let itens       = '';
                let indicadores = '';

                if (videos_pendentes.length > 0) {

                    videos_pendentes.forEach(function(video, indice) {
                        indicadores += '<li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="' + indice + '" class="' + (indice == 0? 'active' : '') + '"></li>'

                        itens += '<div class="carousel-item ' + (indice == 0? 'active' : '') + '">';
                        itens += '    <iframe  width="700" height="450" src="'+ video.urlvideo +'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'; 
                        itens += '</div>';

                    });

                    console.log(indicadores);

                    $('#carouselExampleIndicators').show();
                    $('#carousel-indicadores').html( indicadores );
                    $('#carousel-itens').html( itens );

                } else {

                    alert('Nenhum vídeo pendente');

                }
            });


            $('.carousel').carousel();

        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Em resumo criei uma base de dados bem simplificada e inseri alguns registros. Coloquei dois "nomecomps" como monitores desses vídeos. Os nomes desses monitores são `matheus` e `macario`.

Suponha que a forma de identificar o usuário logado seja pelo "nomecomp", então, ao carregar a tela que mostra os vídeos pendentes, você já deve ter consultado quais são estes vídeos, aplicando as restrições que você desejar. Por fim, você pode lançar os vídeos consultados no banco de dados pelo PHP, em uma variável JS, como mostrado na linha 90 do arquivo index.php.

Se tiver alguma dúvida, comenta aqui.